# Content repository with versioning and full-text search capabilities

Tags: document-management, text-search, document-indexing

I'm looking for a good document store for a project where I'll need to save attachments of almost any kind.

The requirements are:

- full-text search capabilities
- updating/versioning control
- several document types (full-text search initially only on text-based docs, I might take care of further integration on meta-data information, OCR integration or whatever in further steps using Apache Tika or similar tools).
- multi-user capable (I guess this can be also extended in the application side if it's not supported as is)

I am not sure that Jackrabbit and Elasticsearch/SOLR are directly comparable, but it seems to me that both may fulfil my specs. Of course I'm open to other products as long as they meet my requirements.

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) I've adjusted your question accordingly, and hope that fits you. As for the tags used: Must the software be written in Java? Are there any OS-dependencies (e.g. must it run on Windows/Linux/iOS/…)? Must it be accessible via the network? Multi-user capable?

Comment: perfect, and sorry for the extra effort.

Comment: Always glad to help. But can you please fill in the gaps I've mentioned? You can always [edit] your post with additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alfresco](http://alfresco.com/) fits the requirements:

- It includes Solr, and full-text search works out-of-the-box.
- Apache Tika is also included out-of-the-box, so metadata is extracted from most file formats.
- Alfresco of course performs versioning, and is multi-user. I use it everyday to collaborate with my colleagues.

You can use Alfresco either via its UI or via any of the APIs it supports: CMIS, JCR, WebDAV, FTP, CIFS.

OCR is not available out-of-the-box, but I have integrated it (using Tesseract) for a customer, it was relatively easy.

Alfresco is free and open source.

Comment: Can Alfresco be used via API? or is it just an UI over Jackrabbit adding some extra functionality like the apache Tika one?

I need to use the Content repo programatically to integrate it into my application and I saw that Alfresco is built on top of Jackrabbit, so I don't know whether I should go for the basics in this chance. Any clue would be great.

Comment: Alfresco is not based on Jackrabbit. I added to my answer a paragraph listing all of the standard APIs that Alfresco supports.

Comment: Any other alternative in php or python?